# Change tabsetpanel with tag$button

Tags: r, tabs, shiny

I need to use custom buttons to pass from one tab to another. To do this, I've done a custom button `tag$button` in the `ui.R` file and a `updateTabsetPanel` in the `server.R`

The button is the following:

```
tags$button(
    id = "webleft",
    class = "btn action_button",
    tags$img(src='img/arrow-left.png',
    height = "50px")
),
```

To change the tab I have the following function:

```
observeEvent(input$webleft,{
  updateTabsetPanel(session,"inTabset", selected = "Filtres")
})
```

The problem is that with this button, the updateTabsetPanel does not work. Something that with an actionbutton such as `actionButton("webleft", "Button")` does. Any idea in how to solve the problem or any approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The class name should be `action-button` with a hyphen